# Independence of functions of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with Exponential$(1)$ distribution. How can it be shown that
$$
\frac{X}{X+Y}
$$
and
$$X+Y$$
are independent?

Comment: Or use a simple change of variables $(X,Y)\to \left(\frac{X}{X+Y},X+Y\right)$.

Comment: Since you've accepted the Answer below, which is in the form of a hint, it would improve this Question if you provide your own detailed Answer below, demonstrating the claims/computations that are only hinted at so far, for the benefit of future Readers.  I'd avoid posting Questions in the future that are merely problem statements without context.  Context can be provided in many ways, such as showing your approach or explaining why the problem is of interest to you, that will generally help Readers to respond in a suitably helpful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints for one possible approach:

- Find the distribution of $X$ given that ${X+Y}=k\qquad$ (for positive $k$)
- Find the distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ given that ${X+Y}=k$
- Observe that this second conditional distribution does not change with different $k$

Comment: Nice and intuitive! I guess to make this rigorous, a simple statement involving pdfs is the way.